# Passing arguements to Javascript function from aspnet markup

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to pass an argument to a javascript function in the aspnet webform. The function will open a window through on `onClientClick` of a button control in a GridView. I wanted to do this from markup. I tried passing the arguement as below:-

```
 OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("javascript:return
 gdvPopup({0});", Eval("MailID").ToString)%>'
```

MailID field is in Guid format.

When I build the page I get an error message "expected ')'".

The javascript function is as below:-

```
function gdvPopup(MailID) {
var newURL = 'LinkMails.aspx?Inmail_ID=' + inmailID;
window.showModalDialog('' + newURL +'', 'name'
,  'dialogWidth:255px;dialogHeight:250px');
}
```

I am using VS 2012

After trying different combinations, I changed over to adding an attribute to the button control during `GrivView_DataRowBound` event and it works fine.

But can someone point out as to what error am I committing here in the markup? Is there any better way around?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to complete the `()` of `ToString` method

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("javascript:return gdvPopup({0});", Eval("MailID").ToString())%>'
```